# Walking pace and torque

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, torque, inertia

How to understand the relationship between the mass of a person, the length of the legs and the walking pace? My professor tried to explain it but I didn't quite get it.

So we can consider the hips as the point of rotation. [image]

If we consider the legs to be thin rods, we can say the moment of inertia of the legs is

$$I=\frac {1}{12}mL^2$$

Up to this point, everything is clear, but then I have no idea how this is related to one's height and weight. Say if I have longer, heavier legs, that means I need more force to move my legs, sure, but that also makes my step much larger, doesn't it? I could imagine that the walking speed is related to the mass of a person. But then if we consider the moment of the legs as oscillations, then the mass of the person doesn't matter anymore, does it?

But then my professor said if given a person's weight, length of the legs, the mass of the legs, we can calculate the frequency of the moments of the legs (if we consider them oscillations), he didn't elaborate on that, but how is that possible? Doesn't the angle need to be specified?

I tried a lot of ways to numerically calculate the frequency of the rotation of the legs, because the professor said its possible, but I just cannot....Can someone quickly explain what he meant, or generally what's missing here?

Comment: I suggest that you show how you tried to solve this problem - then somebody will be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps he was referring to the time period of a pendulum of length $L$

$$T=2\pi\sqrt{\frac{L}{g}}$$

It's independent of mass and angle and $f=1/T$.  The formula above is for a bob at the end of a string, but you could look for something similar for a rod.